# M. M. Artyukhov / М. М. Артюхов

Tags: ho.history-overview

Does anybody know any biographical information about [М. М. Артюхов](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/person.phtml?&personid=34845&option_lang=eng) (e.g., first name, affiliation)?

It seems he discovered a criterion for primality equivalent to the Solovay–Strassen one in 1966, in this paper: [Некоторые критерии простоты чисел, связанные с малой теоремой Ферма](https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/acta-arithmetica/all/12/4/96314/nekotorye-kriterii-prostoty-chisel-svjazannye-s-maloj-teoremoj-ferma).
(Keith Conrad discusses the story a little bit here: [The Miller–Rabin test](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/millerrabin.pdf).)

I'm just curious. :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the books [1], pp. 41-42 and [2], p. 67, it is stated that his name (and patronymic) is Mikhail Mikhailovich, confirming [Anatoly Kochubei's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414522/m-m-artyukhov-%d0%9c-%d0%9c-%d0%90%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8e%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b2/414688#comment1063272_414525) to [Kostya_I's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/414525/113756). References also state that he was born on the 26 of April 1910 in Moscow, laureated from (the then called) Leningrad University in 1936, become "aspirant" (aspirant in science) until 1939, then "kandidat fiz.-matem. nauk" (candidate in physics and mathematical sciences) and "docent" (professor) from 1945 onward. After 1954 he worked at the North Caucasus (Ordzhonikidze) Metallurgical Institute ([1], p. 41), thus Kostya_I's answer is further confirmed. In [1], p. 42, there's a list of six of his works, the first being dated 1934 and the latest one being dated 1957: in [2], p. 67, the list is continued with four more works, dated from 1958 to 1963.

**References**

[1] Fomin, S. V.; Shilov, G. E., eds. (1970), Математика в СССР 1958–1967 [Mathematics in the USSR 1958–1967] (in Russian),  Том второй: Биобиблиография выпуск второй М–Я, Москва: Издательство "Наука", p. 762, [MR 0250816](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0250816), [Zbl 0199.28501](https://zbmath.org/?&q=an:0199.28501).

[2] Kurosh, A. G.; Vityushkov, V. I.; Boltyanskii, V. G.; Dynkin, E. B.; Shilov, G. E.; Yushkevich, A. P., eds. (1959), Математика в СССР за сорок лет 1917–1957 [Mathematics in the USSR 1917–1957] (in Russian), Том второй: Биобиблиография, Москва: Государственное Издательство Физико–Математическои Литературы, p. 819, [MR 0115874](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0115874), [Zbl 0191.27501](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0191.27501).

Comment: Great stuff, thanks!

Comment: @RyanO'Donnell I am glad to have been of some help. 

Comment: @LSpice, no problem, I'll delete mine. But this gives me the occasion to thank you since by seeing your edits, I've learned to include links to important comments, not only Q&A. :)

Comment: @DanieleTampieri, happy if I've helped!

Answer (score 19):

He was a docent in charge of the Chair of Mathematical analysis in what is now North Ossetia State University in Vladikavkaz. At the time, the city was called Ordzhonikidze, and the university was a "pedagogical institute".

[Source.](https://www.nosu.ru/facultet/it/kafedry/kafedra-matematicheskogo-analiza/) There's an e-mail address there (the one starting with kmatan); you probably can enquire if you are interested in further details.

Comment: Ah, interesting!  FWIW, the list of his papers on mathnet.ru ends in 1962, which is before his two papers on primality tests appeared: http://www.mathnet.ru/php/person.phtml?&personid=34845&option_lang=eng

Comment: On the page http://ntb.spbgasu.ru/cgi-bin/irbis64r_15/cgiirbis_64.exe?LNG=&C21COM=S&I21DBN=IBIS&P21DBN=IBIS&S21FMT=fullwebr&S21ALL=%28%3C%2E%3EK%3D%D0%A2%D0%A0%D0%A3%D0%94%D0%AB%20%D0%A1%D0%AA%D0%95%D0%97%D0%94%D0%90%3C%2E%3E%29&Z21ID=&S21SRW=AVHEAD&S21SRD=&S21STN=1&S21REF=&S21CNR=30 a book of talks from the 2nd All-Union Mathematical Congress in 1934 lists M. M. Artyukhov's talk on "Solution to a problem connected with the reciprocity law" (search for the word взаимности and there's just one hit).

Comment: I sent an email to the indicated address to see what the department knows about him.

Comment: @KConrad, mathnet.ru indexes primarily (only?) publications in Russian venues.  Artjukhov's later papers were in Acta Arithmetica, the latest one in 1975.

Comment: Do report back KConrad, thanks!

Comment: A little more is written here: https://www.skgmi-gtu.ru/ru-ru/faculties/asf/cathedra/fmd In particular, his first name and patronimic were Mikhail Mikhailovich.

Comment: Should be Vladikavkaz, right?

Comment: @AnatolyKochubei it's unbelievable that the page you linked to includes the line Последней научной победой Биллевича К.К. было доказательство великой теоремы Ферма, эта работа была депонирована в 1987г в ВИНИТИ.

Comment: @RyanO'Donnell no reply yet.  The email address is generic (kmatan is just an abbreviation for "mathematical analysis department"), so possibly nobody is even reading it.  Fortunately you have already received some very good information here.

Comment: @KConrad, what's the translation of [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414522/m-m-artyukhov-%d0%9c-%d0%9c-%d0%90%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8e%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b2#comment1063843_414525)?

Comment: @LSpice, Google translate is adequate: "The last scientific victory of Billevich K.K. was a proof of Fermat's Last Theorem, this work was deposited in 1987 at VINITI." "Deposited" refers to the practice of making an unpublished manuscript publicly available by archiving a physical copy in a library.

Comment: @LSpice in this case победа is better translated as triumph, which you probably already realized.  How did you determine the comment number to create your link?

Comment: @KConrad, I know not a whit of Russian, so had to rely on @‍Kostya_I's (via Google) [translation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414522/m-m-artyukhov-%d0%9c-%d0%9c-%d0%90%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8e%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b2/414525#comment1064894_414525).  The timestamp next to a comment is, for some reason secretly, actually a link to the comment.